# Bot Framework start a conversation, send a (non reply) message

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I am using the Bot Framework Rest API with Node. I am successfully sending reply messages upon a user sending a message (in MS Teams).

I am now trying to start a conversation, to which the response comes back successful, with a conversation id.
( POST /v3/conversations returns me an id - great!)

Then, I try to send a message to that conversation id and I keep getting Service error 'Unknown'. I have tried everything..

Get token function (works fine)
[image]

Create a conversation (works fine)
[image]

Using the conversationId above, send a message (Not working):
[image]
[image]

I am following the documentation provided:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-conversation

Step 1, create a conversation:
[image]
[image]

Step 2, send message using conversation id from above:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see nobody is posting so in case someone finds this and wants more detail, here is an on-going conversation about it - https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/260

Comment: did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages Maybe, it now works?